# Target selected option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to display an alert when user selects any option other than "choose" which is selected by default. I tried to target whether selected option has value but this doesn't work. This is what I have, don't have access to html:

```js
if (jQuery('#select_1 option').val()) {
  jQuery('#select_1').append('<span>you selected an option</span>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
<option value>choose</option>
<option value="111">1</option>
<option value="112">2</option>
<option value="113">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try jQuery('#select_1').val() != "" instead

Comment: try change `<option value>choose</option>` to `<option value="">choose</option>`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you should hook to the `change` event of the `select` and check the selected value.

Also note that you cannot `append()` any elements other than `option` to a `select`. It would be better to have the `span` in the DOM on load, but hidden. You can then `toggle()` it based on the selected value, something like this:

```js
$('#select_1').change(function() {
  $('#alert').toggle(this.value !== '');
});
```

```css
#alert { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="111">1</option>
  <option value="112">2</option>
  <option value="113">3</option>
</select>

<span id="alert">you selected an option</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't add the span via html - in my case it's dynamically generated and I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting the selected option, you're selecting all the options. Then `.val()` returns the value of the first one.

Instead of getting the value of the option, get the value of the `<select>`, which is the value of the selected option.

```js
$("#select_1").change(function() {
  if (this.value) {
    $("#output").append('<span>you selected an option</span>');
  } else {
    $("#output").empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
    <option value>choose</option>
    <option value="111">1</option>
    <option value="112">2</option>
    <option value="113">3</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also, you shouldn't append the message to `#select_1`. The contents of a `<select>` should only be `<option>` and `<optgroup>`.

Comment: Thanks, right now alert is displaying multiple times when different option is selected. Is it possible to display it only once?

Comment: You could use a global variable that remembers whether they selected a value the previous time. Then only show the alert if the variable says nothing was selected before and they selected something this time.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. I have used `$(select).val()` rather than using `val()` on the option elements.

```js
$('#select_1').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val().trim() === '' ){
    alert('Please select a value!');
   } else {
    alert('You selected value:' + $(this).val());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
    <option value>choose</option>
    <option value="111">1</option>
    <option value="112">2</option>
    <option value="113">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select_1").change(function(){
        if( $('#select_1').val() != '' ) {
            var text = $('#select_1 :selected').text();
            var value = $('#select_1 :selected').val();
            $('#appendDiv').append("<br><span>You selected an option with text:" + text + " and value: " + value + "</span>");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
    <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="111">1</option>
    <option value="112">2</option>
    <option value="113">3</option>
</select>
<div id="appendDiv"> </div>
```